# get Asset property in layout (Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In `app\assets\LoginAsset`

I appoint new property `public $bodyCss = 'login';`.

In my view i'm calling it by `LoginAsset::register($this);`.
And in my layout i want to use `$bodyCss` here:

`<body class="<?= /*get($bodyCss)*/ ?>">`

If i'm calling `var_dump($this->assetBundles)` i see my `["bodyCss"]=> string(13) "login"` property

but how to use it?

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use in this way

```
 <body class="<?= $this->assetBundles["bodyCss"]; ?>">
```